# net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING since upgrading to Laravel 4.1

Tags: google-chrome, laravel, laravel-4

I've recently upgraded my app to Laravel 4.1 and I started getting this error (Chrome only)

```
net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

in the console log. I have zero errors related to this in Laravel's logs and the same page works absolutely fine in Firefox or Safari. Can anyone help? I've been pulling my hair over this for quite a while now and I have no idea what else to try.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try running a 'clean' fresh install of 4.1 and see if you still get the error.

Comment: I think I may have just realised that this issue is due to a class using a trait. I just have no clue why this is happening tho.

Comment: Seems to be a Windows registry problem. Not specificly Laravel.

Comment: I also notice that virus software like Kaspersky are often to blame.

Comment: I have exact same thing, on OSX Mavericks with Laravel 4.1 and traits

Comment: See with Chrome Private Mode ( CTR+SHIFT+N). Sometime some of chrome extension errors see to chrome console, so check it with Private Mode!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? I am running 5.4 and got this error with Laravel 4.2...

Comment: Try updating PHP version to 5.5.

Answer (score 9):

I started having this issues with MAMP, Laravel and Chrome every time i created a new project.
I use MAMP on Maverick so the solution for me was change on MAMP preferences -> php tab -> php extensions -> XCache to APC, that solved the problem.
Good luck.

Comment: @Manuel : thats solve my problem.. but do you know what causes this?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue on Laravel 4.2. My app has always been working on my local machine, but as soon as I put it on production server, it stopped working. As the answer above, **XCache** installed on the production server was the problem.

First of all you can check if XCache is enabled

```
$ php -v
...
with XCache v2.0.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2012, by mOo
```

What I did was to add this to my /public/**.htaccess** (to disable XCache)

```
php_flag xcache.cacher Off
php_flag xcache.size 0
php_flag xcache.stat Off
```

This way you check if XCache is the problem.