# ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING on a fresh Laravel install

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, laravel, chromium

This only happens on Google Chrome and Chromium with a fresh install of Laravel.

The page shows blank and in the console it says:

> (failed) net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Instead of the default hello view that which says “You have arrived.”

My server is Debian Wheezy with ISPConfig, Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4

Does anybody knows how can I fix this?

Comment: It says "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"

Comment: If I try without the "-I" it spits the HTML and finally "curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining"

Comment: I'm using Laravel 4.2, I've tried going back to 4.1 and it works. How can I find the issue?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470537/neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-since-upgrading-to-laravel-4-1

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on a Ubuntu 14.04 Vagrant box running nginx. The site is a Laravel 5 that one day surprisingly started throwing those errors.

After reading this comment:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/issues/262#issuecomment-74385850

I've checked my `/var/log/nginx/vagrant.com-error.log.1` and saw:

> [crit] 1020#0: *774 open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/3/03/0000000033" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.56.1, server: 192.168.56.102.xip.io, request: "GET /_debugbar/assets/javascript?1423122680 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my-host", referrer: "http://url/that/fails"

Double-checked my Vagrant box nginx lib directory permissions `ll /var/lib/`

> drwxr-xr-x  7 root    root    4096 feb  9 11:28 nginx/

... where internally was using `www-data` user: `ll /var/lib/nginx/`

> drwx------ 12 www-data root 4096 may  5 13:32 fastcgi/

So I ran:

> chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx

And the error in Chrome disappeared.

Just posting here to notice the solution, even all the credits should go to the linked original comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem that you have. I found a work-around over here on this forum thread:
http://laravel.io/forum/02-08-2014-another-problem-only-with-chrome

The code used by the person who provided a the workaround: http://laravel.io/bin/eyyDj#4,7
The gist of it is to just up and tell Chrome how much data to expect for every request, so it doesn't have to chunk the data.

I'm seeing reports that upgrading to PHP 5.5 also fixes this problem, but not all of us can have that kind of control over our servers.

**Edit:** It looks as if blindly applying this work-around causes errors on redirects. This is the code that I'm now using:

```
App::after(function($request, $response) {
    // Fixes a strange issue with Chrome. Should theoretically be removeable
    // after upgrading PHP to 5.5 from 5.4
    if ($response instanceof Illuminate\Http\Response) {
        $response->header('Content-Length', strlen($response->getOriginalContent()));
    }
});
```

Note that JSON responses are a separate type and may still have the chunking issue, so this solution may need to evolve somewhat to accommodate that.

Comment: Where should I put this code? I have PHP 5.5 and the problem persists.